# Why JQGrid failed to show data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

In the following code, the action method `GetData()` to load data to **jqgrid**. But what funny was it showed it had data but the rows did not display data, the pager component has shown it has multiple pages and i could click rows it even shown the blue border color when i clicked on a row but still did not display data.

I did everything that i could find the issue, is there a way to fix this?

The Action method:

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public JsonResult GetData()
{
    try
    {
        var customers = db.Customers.Select(x => new { x.CustomerID, x.FirstName, x.MiddleName,x.CompanyName, x.SalesPerson, x.EmailAddress }).ToList();
        return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

The View:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<h2>Index</h2>

<table id="customerGrid"></table>
<div id="pager1"></div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {

            jQuery("#customerGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'Home/GetData',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "GET",
                postData:'',
                colNames: ['Customer ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name'],
                colModel: [
                    { name: 'customerid', index: 'CustomerID', key:true,sorttype:'int', width: 100 },
                    { name: 'firstname', index: 'FirstName', width: 100 },                    
                    { name: 'lastname', index: 'LastName', width: 100 }                    
                ],
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: true,
                loadonce: true, //if all data loaded at once
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#pager1',
                sortname: 'customerid',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "Customer List",
                width:600
            });
            jQuery("#customerGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1', { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
        })
    </script>


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you **never use `index` property** in `colModel`. To fix the problem you should use correct values for `name` properties in `colModel`. For example:

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'CustomerID', key: true, sorttype: 'int' },
    { name: 'FirstName' },                    
    { name: 'LastName' }                    
],
cmTemplate: { width: 100 }
```

I used `cmTemplate: { width: 100 }` to reduce duplicating of `width: 100` in every column of `colModel`.

I'd recommend you to use additionally `height: "auto"` and `jsonReader: { id: "CustomerID" }`. After specifying of `jsonReader.id` you can consider to remove `CustomerID` column. jqGrid will still assign `id` attribute of rows (id of `<tr>` elements of the grid), known as rowids.

The option `sortname: 'customerid'` is wrong too and it has no effect. If you use old jqGrid 4.6 then *the server* have to return correctly sorted data. I'd recommend you to upgrade to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.4. You can load it from CDN: see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) (including of `grid.locale-en.js` is not needed in free jqGrid) or to install from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/free-jqgrid) or [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid). After that you can use `forceClientSorting: true`, which works in combination with `loadonce: true`. It allows to sort or filter the data returned from the server *before* displaying the first page.

Comment: What's the commonly used jqgrid version?

Comment: is there a proper documentation for JQGrid and videos

Comment: @vitofila: There are no "common used" jqGrid version. It was developed originally at trirand by Tony Tomov and it was available for free under MIT/GPLv2 licenses. He posted [the statement](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438), renamed jqGrid to Guriddo jqGrid JS and made it commercial (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). After that I started the fork "free jqGrid", which is based on jqGrid 4.7, made many bug fixes and implemented many new features. I use 4.x.y as the version number because I try to hold **compatibility with old versions of jqGrid**.

Comment: @vitofila: There are exist "old" documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs). Free jqGrid in compatible with old jqGrid and thus the most information is still correct. There are many information in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki), in READMEs to every published erly version of free jqGrid and there are exist [the preliminary documentation](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html). There are no videos as I know. The current version of free jqGrid is 4.13.4. I recommend you to use it.

Comment: is the trirand jqgrid (this was i was using in that example) a fully fledged professionally used plugin?

Comment: i'm planning to use Jqgrid in ReactJS native apps, can i count on your JqGrid not to fail in ReactJS native apps? (no offense on this its better to check first with than been sorry later)

Comment: @vitofila: I can't follow you. I wrote you in the previously comment that I develop **free jqGrid** fork since the end of 2014, but you asked me about some unknown version of trirand jqgrid, which you use. One can use jqGrid in different environments. ReactJS has life-cycle methods `componentDidMount`, `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, ..., which allows to integrate any DOM based component or jQuery plugin inside of React component. Thus I see no problems.